# How to prevent landscape orientation media queries to load

Tags: html, css

Title might be a little bit confusing, but let me explain. The problem is that I'm making an adaptive site, which has several number inputs. My css is constructed this way:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 940px){
  // General styles for both orientations to prevent from duplicating same code
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  // Styles that only landscape orientation needs
}
```

Any time input is focused, mobiles keyboard shows up and all my styles switch to landscape orientation (as much as I understand, because the width is larger than height and it thinks that device is in landscape orient.) However, I don't want this to happen. And if the keyboard appears, I want styles to stay as they were.

Therefore, what are the ways to prevent this problem happen?

Comment: I guess, some styles I need to move to a new media query for portrait orientation, but will it help anyway?

Comment: You can also use min-with, max-height, min-height to help confine your styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Force the content to not scale, and to be fixed to the device screen size.